# Комментирование с использованием jQuery

Tags: jquery, php

Написал вот такой скрипт для комментирования:

```
function add_comments() {
    $.post("<?echo$home;?>/pages/str/add_comments.php?id=<?echo$row['id'];?>", {
        text: $("#text").val()
    },

    function (data) {
        if (data.split("|%%%^&|")[0] != "ok") {
            $("#error_error").html("<div class=\"alert alert-error\"><a class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" href=\"#\"></a>" + data + "</div>");
        } else {
            $("#result").html(data.split("|%%%^&|")[1]);
            $("#error_error").html("<div class=\"alert alert-info\"><a class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" href=\"#\"></a>Комментарий успешно добавлен!</div>");
        }
    });
}
```

Обработчик

```
<?
require_once '../../system/core.php';
#### ДОбавление коментов
$row  = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE `id`='" . $id . "'"));
$text = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['text']));

if (mb_strlen($text) < 2 || mb_strlen($text) > 1000) {
    echo 'Недопустимая длина текста комментария';
    exit;
}

//если нет ошибок - пишем в базу
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `news_comments` SET `id_user` = '" . $user['id'] . "', `id_news` = '" . $row['id'] . "', `text` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($text) . "', `time` = '" . $realtime . "'");
echo "ok";
echo '|%%%^&|';
############Вывод коментов    
echo '<div class="grid_9 margin_bottom_20px"><div class="margin_left_20px_right_2px">';
$reqcomments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news_comments` WHERE `id_news`='" . $row['id'] . "' ORDER BY `id` DESC");
while ($rowcomments = mysql_fetch_assoc($reqcomments)) {
    $rowcomments['text'] = str_replace("\r\n", "<br/>", $rowcomments['text']);
    $avtor_comments      = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from `users` WHERE `id`='" . $rowcomments['id_user'] . "'"));
    echo '<div class="com_level1 margin_bottom_20px" id="ok_comments-' . $rowcomments['id'] . '>
                        <div class="ava">';
    if (!empty($avtor_comments['avatar'])) {
        echo '<img src="' . $home . '/files/avatar/' . $avtor_comments['avatar'] . '" alt=""/>';
    } else {
        echo '<img src="' . $home . '/files/avatar/photo.jpg" alt=""/>';
    }
    echo '</div>
                        <div class="comment">
                            <div><h3><a href="' . $home . '/profile.php?id=' . $avtor_comments['id'] . '" class="underline_none">' . $avtor_comments['login'] . '</a><div style="text-align:right; margin: -15px;">' . times($rowcomments['time']) . '</div></h3></div>
                            <div><br/><p>' . $rowcomments['text'] . '</p></div>';
    if ($user['level'] == 100)
        echo ' <span id="del_comments"><a href="#" onclick="del(' . $rowcomments['id'] . ');return false;"><font color="red">удалить комментарий</font></a></span>';
    echo '</div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>';
}
if ($user['id']) {
    echo '<div id="error_error"></div>';
    echo '<textarea id="text" rows="5" class="inp_text_5 margin_bottom_8px" placeholder="Введите ваш комментарий" required></textarea>
    <br/><input type="button" class="btn" value="Добавить комментарий" onclick="add_comments()">';
}
echo '</div></div><div class="clear"></div>';
?>
```

---

Но возникла еще одна проблемка: если на одной странице находится несколько новостей и к каждой новости комментарии, то такой код работать не будет.

Вопрос: что нужно добавить в jQuery код, чтобы заработало?

Comment: когда вы уже начнёте разделять логику и представления

Comment: @Spectre, думаю не скоро, Попов детектед!

Answer (score 1):

В коде вы используете "#result", который должен быть уникальным на странице, вполне может быть, что в этом дело. До конца уверенным не могу, т.к. вашу кашу из html и php разбирать не охота.

PS почему бы вам не использовать

- отдельный файл для обработки данных
     (*.php), который будет обрабатывать
     ajax запросы
- отдельный файл для отображения
     новостей и все страницы в целом
     (*.html |* .php)
- отдельный файл для javascript (*.js)
     для собственно javascript
- пожалуйста, для работы с базой
     данных пользуйтесь PDO, не
     отпихивайте развитие PHP на 15 лет
     назад, это же удобней, безопасней и
     намного повышает читабельность
     (=скорость нахождения багов) вашего
     же кода.

Comment: Так я и использую разные файлы.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что код этот принимает только одну новость, по её `id`. Тебе просто нужно добавлять `id` той новости, к которой добавляешь комент.

Например, при формировании новостей добавлять скрытый `input`, записывать туда `id` новости, и при отправке скрипту отправлять этот `id`.

Comment: $.post("<?echo$home;?>/pages/add_news_comments.php?id=<?echo$row['id'];?>" тут же ИД новости передается.